# How can we automate service connection creation process in azure devops

Tags: azure-devops, azure-pipelines

Given that azure app service setup is done in azure portal and azure devops pipeline is setup as well except the service connection.
Is there a way to automate service connection creation using arm template based infrastructure yaml pipeline?
We want to run this pipeline and update service connection in user yaml pipeline.

Comment: If you create a service connection through the UI, you can get the specific JSON for that type of Service Connection. Turn on Developer Tools (F12) and then turn on network logging. Look for a POST to endpoint and then copy the Request out. Format it as JSON, and you've got yourself something you can use to repeat later.

Comment: https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/rest/api/azure/devops/serviceendpoint/endpoints/create

Comment: Or you can get froggy and make a completely custom one. https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/azure/devops/extend/develop/service-endpoints

Answer (score 5, accepted):

> Is there a way to automate service connection creation using arm
>   template based infrastructure yaml pipeline?

**ARM template** is used to deploy the azure service. It can not used to creating a service connection in azure devops until now.

Based on your scenario, I think you can consider to make use of [rest api](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/rest/api/azure/devops/serviceendpoint/endpoints/create?view=azure-devops-rest-5.1) by using **Powershell** task with below script:

```
$token = "{PAT token}"

$url="https://dev.azure.com/{org name}/{project name}/_apis/serviceendpoint/endpoints?api-version=5.1-preview.2"

$token = [System.Convert]::ToBase64String([System.Text.Encoding]::ASCII.GetBytes(":$($token)"))

$body = @"
{
  "authorization": {
    "parameters": {
      "tenantid": "{tenant id}",
      "serviceprincipalid": "{principal id}",
      "authenticationType": "spnKey",
      "serviceprincipalkey": "{principal key}"
    },
    "scheme": "ServicePrincipal"
  },
  "data": {
    "subscriptionId": "{subscription id}",
    "subscriptionName": "{subscription name}",
    "environment": "AzureCloud",
    "scopeLevel": "Subscription"
  },
  "name": "{service connection name}",
  "type": "azurerm",
  "url": "https://management.azure.com/"
}
"@

$response = Invoke-RestMethod -Uri $url -Headers @{Authorization = "Basic $token"} -Method Post -Body $Body -ContentType application/json
```

You will see that the corresponding service connection is created after this task executed.