# How to create service connection Azure DevOps from type AzureRM (automatic) (using service principal- automatic)

Tags: azure, azure-devops, azure-cli, serviceconnection

I need to create a connection from many projects in Azure DevOps to my subscription in Azure.
I also need him will be from type azure resource manager and that their service principal will be create automatily.

I try to use Azure CLI but the only solution that I found to create azureRM  (as written in this link: [create azurerm service endpoint](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/cli/azure/devops/service-endpoint/azurerm?view=azure-cli-latest)) but you need to give him a service principal that already exists.

How I can create a service connection that will be created automatically service principal?
like in the UI options:
[azurerm - service principal (aoutomatic)](https://i.stack.imgur.com/DFpyr.png)

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Unfortunately, There's no other command to create Azure Service connection automatically. Refer [here](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/azure/devops/pipelines/library/connect-to-azure?view=azure-devops#create-a-new-workload-identity-federation-service-connection) And for service principal and managed identity you need to create it manually. [Refer here](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/azure/devops/pipelines/release/configure-workload-identity?view=azure-devops#workload-identity-with-a-service-principal).

As this option is still in Public Preview not all features are available.

You need to create it with the [**`CLI command`**](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/cli/azure/devops/service-endpoint?view=azure-cli-latest) below, by mentioning your Service Principal details:-

***CLI Command:-***

```bash
az devops service-endpoint azurerm create --azure-rm-service-principal-id "xxxxx6d26a31435cb" --azure-rm-subscription-id "xxxxx7cb2a7" --azure-rm-subscription-name "xxx subscription" --azure-rm-tenant-id "xxxxx-af9038592395" --name "AzureSp"
```

**Output:-**

[image]

[image]

You can achieve same result with Azure CLI Task in Azure DevOps:-

YAML pipeline:-

```yaml
trigger:
- main

pool:
  vmImage: ubuntu-latest

variables:
 AZURE_DEVOPS_EXT_PAT: xxxxxxxxzz2jo34pa

steps:
- task: AzureCLI@2
  inputs:
    azureSubscription: 'xxx subscription (xxxxxxxxxxxa7)'
    scriptType: 'bash'
    scriptLocation: 'inlineScript'
    inlineScript: |
      #export AZURE_DEVOPS_EXT_PAT=xxxxxxxz2jo34pa
      export AZURE_DEVOPS_EXT_AZURE_RM_SERVICE_PRINCIPAL_KEY=xxxxxxx4_w0N4Yc9B
      echo $(AZURE_DEVOPS_EXT_PAT) | az devops login --organization https://dev.azure.com/sid24desai0738
      
      az devops service-endpoint azurerm create --azure-rm-service-principal-id "xxxxxx403c-9fe4-11971d950312" --azure-rm-subscription-id "xxxxxxxxxxe97cb2a7" --azure-rm-subscription-name "xxx subscription" --azure-rm-tenant-id "xxxxx038592395" --name "Azuremyapp"
```

You can also call the Rest API to achieve the same task, Refer this [SO Answer](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/60664369/how-can-we-automate-service-connection-creation-process-in-azure-devops)